# Incorrect ToC/Index cross-references when resetting memoir class counters

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, memoir, counters

The quasi-MWE below uses the `memoir` class and works fine. It produces a document with the following structure:

- ToC
- Book

  - Part1
  - Chapter1
  - Part2
  - Chapter2
- Index

Here, cross-references in the ToC and in the Index all work correctly. But I want to reset Chapter numbers back to "1" in each Part (and ultimately, in each Book, if there are many books). To do so, I uncomment the `\counterwithin` instructions in the preamble.

Now, depending on the value assigned to `hyperref`'s `hypertexnames` option, I get the following behaviour:

- if `true`, the ToC link to Chapter "2" in Part 2 (which is now renumbered to "1") does not works, but the Index link to AAAAA on page "5" does;
- if `false`, the ToC link to Chapter "2" in Part 2 (which is now renumbered to "1") works, but the Index link to AAAAA on page "5" does not.

Am I doing something wrong?

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}

%\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}           % Restarts chapter count within Part.

\usepackage{hyperref}             
\hypersetup{
    hypertexnames=true,                
    linktocpage=false,
    colorlinks=true,                                        
}
\indexintoc
\makeindex[main]

\begin{document}
\frontmatter{}
\tableofcontents*
\mainmatter{}
\book{BookTitleA}
 \part{PartTitleA}
  \chapter{TitleA}
AAAAA\index[main]{AAAAA}.\\
 \part{PartTitleB}
  \chapter{TitleB}
BBBBB.
\backmatter
 \clearpage
 \printindex[main]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}

%\counterwithin*{chapter}{part} % Restarts chapter count within Part.

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{ hypertexnames=true,
             linktocpage=false, 
             colorlinks=true,
} 
\indexintoc 
\makeindex[main]

\begin{document} 
\frontmatter{} 
\tableofcontents* 
\mainmatter{} 
\book{BookTitleA} 
 \part{PartTitleA} 
  \chapter{TitleA} 
  AAAAA\index[main]{AAAAA}.
 \part{PartTitleB} 
  \chapter{TitleB} 
  BBBBB. 
\backmatter 
\clearpage 
\printindex[main] 
\end{document}`

Comment: My apologies for my formatting failures.

Comment: If you need to modify your original question, click on the `edit` and add the relevant code, rather than posting uncommented code in a comment. Once you're done, clean up the comments section be removing the non-relevant ones.

Comment: The latex code initially appeared mangled in my post. That's why I commented in order to fix it (I'll do what you suggest, from now on). However, I see that the code is now properly formatted, I just don't know why or how to ensure that it will be in future posts.

Comment: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code). The latter also holds for comments, as you already know.

Comment: This is similar to the problem given at [this c.t.t discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/msg/b32c2d6f9f23d8e1?dmode=source). I'm not yet sure how much of the code is relevant to this variant, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply moving `\counterwithin*` after `\hypersetup` seems to solve the problem:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}             
\hypersetup{
    hypertexnames=true,                
    linktocpage=false,
    colorlinks=true,                                        
}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}
```

Comment: I was searching for this solution for many hours now. There are lots of different tipps, but this is the only solution which worked for me!