# How can I reset sectional counters in memoir class to avoid breaking ToC cross-referencing in a complex document?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, memoir, counters

I have already asked a similar question here:

[Incorrect ToC/Index cross-references when resetting memoir class counters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32076/incorrect-toc-index-cross-references-when-resetting-memoir-class-counters)

and received a satisfactory answer. Now, I wish to apply the chapter counter reset (using `\counterwithin*`) to a more complex document, but this seems to fail. I simply wish to restart the chapter counter within each Part of a Book, and within each Book of my document structure, which goes like this:

- Book1

  - Part1

    - Chapter1
    - ...
  - Part2

    - Chapter1
    - ...
  - ...
- Book2

  - Chapter1
  - ...
- Book3

  - Chapter1
  - ...

I currently have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{hyperref}             
\hypersetup{
    hypertexnames=true,                
    linktocpage=false,
    colorlinks=true,                                        
}

\counterwithin*{chapter}{book}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\book{Book1}
 \part{Part1}
  \chapter{Chapter1}
 \part{Part2}
  \chapter{Chapter1}

\book{Book2}
  \chapter{Chapter1}

\book{Book3}
  \chapter{Chapter1}

\end{document}
```

I can't seem to get proper cross-referencing in my ToC for chapters in Book2 and Book3. Should I splice the `\counterwithin*` commands somehow throughout the sections?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because you have duplicate chapter numbers, you need to tell `hyperref` to use a unique number for the links.  You can add the following to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand*{\theHchapter}{\thepart.\thebook.\thechapter}
```

You can see the warnings in the log file when this arises.