# How to reset chapter and section counter with \part

Tags: sectioning, numbering, counters

To get the output Toc or pdf bookmark below:

```
Part I
    Chapter I
    Chapter II
Part II
    Chapter I
    Chapter II
```

I need to reset the chapter counter. I google and get one method.

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother
```

Yes, It can output like this. But `hyperref` package can not link to right target for chapters after **chapter I**. That is said page ref link broken.

I like to define all style in style file. the mini-document:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{mini} % my own style file

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Test}
\chapter{One}
\chapter{Two}
\part{Test}
\chapter{Three}
\chapter{Four}
\end{document}
```

and the mini style file:

```
\renewcommand\part{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
\setcounter{chapter}{0}} % I reset manually here.
```

Comment: Have you made two runs after the change?

Comment: Please post exactly, what pdflatex reports on this error.

Comment: have a look at AlanMunn's answer to [how-can-i-reset-sectional-counters-in-memoir-class-to-avoid-breaking-toc-cross-r](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35843/how-can-i-reset-sectional-counters-in-memoir-class-to-avoid-breaking-toc-cross-r) and consider accepting answers to your previous questions- 50% is very low

Comment: By resetting the chapter counter to `0` every time you issue a `\part` command, you generate multiple instances of this counter taking on values `1`, `2`, etc. However, `hyperref` needs a unique hook for each hyperlink it's supposed to create. Would you be willing to consider numbering your chapters as `\thepart\thechapter`? This could be achieved by loading the `chngcntr` package and issuing the command `\numberwithin{chapter}{part}`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This small example is working fine for me:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother  

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Test}
\chapter{One}
\chapter{Two}
\part{Test}
\chapter{Three}
\chapter{Four}
\end{document}
```

So please provide your minimal example showing the problem.
Thank you.

Comment: see the revised question.

Comment: @pythonee The example works fine.

Comment: @pythonee you should try to clean (remove) all the auxiliary files, especially `.aux` and `.out`

Answer (score 8):

The problem is not one of counters but your redefinition of part. Your command `\part`, just handles page opening then it zeroes the chapter. Since your counter is not a subsidiary counter of `part` the link for the first chapter 1 and the second chapter 1 is the same.

As a matter of fact `pdfTeX` issues a warning:

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{chapter.1}) 
has been  already used, duplicate ignored
```

Like web hyperlinks, you cannot have a link pointing to two different destinations.

To correct the issue you can add the chapter counter to the reset list,

```
   \makeatletter
   \@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
   \makeatother
```

or save `book.cls` to `mybook.cls` and change the line `\newcounter {chapter}` to:

```
   \newcounter {chapter}[part]
```

This will work provided you have a proper definition of part (that increments a part counter). As a matter of interest your redefinition of `\part` does nothing really other than give you trouble. It accepts no parameters! (Have a look at `book.cls` for similar definitions).

Comment: It is worth to mention that `\@addtoreset` has to be issued *after* `hyperref` was loaded.

Answer (score 6):

You should use the chngcntr package, which in essence is equivalent to `\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}`. But it's cleaner to use a package isn't it ;)

Also, notice that it should be loaded *after* the hyperref and bookmark packages to ensure the links are correct.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{chapter}{part}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Test}
\chapter{One}

\part{Test2}
\chapter{Two}

\end{document}
```

In addition, `\counterwithin` will rename all chapter/section/etc. labels and prepend the part to it, e.g. section 2.2. becomes IV.2.2 or whatever. If you don't want this, use `\counterwithin*`.