# How can I reset a counter when calling two different environments?

Tags: counters

I defined my own counter which resets every time I call the environment ``environment1''. It works as expected.

```
\newcounter{ado}[environment1]
```

I wanted it to be reseted as well when I call the environment ``environment2''. Is there a simple way like the following?

```
\newcounter{ado}[environment1,environment2]
```

I am using

```
\setcounter{ado}{0}
```

prior to evironment2 environments but i was looking for anything more appropriate.

Comment: This seems very similar to [How to reset chapter and section counter with `\part`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54383/5764) where you can use `\makeatletter \@addtoreset{ado}{environment2} \makeatother`.

Comment: Yes, it worked properly. I wrote it just after the counter's declaration.

Comment: Unless environment1 and enbironment2 are counters, this shouldn't do anything.   If you don't already have counters being incremented by environments, go ahead and  use \setcounter{ado}{0}