# Propertly restart chapter on unnumbered `\part*`

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, hyperref, parts

Following, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54386/15210) I've been able to start anew the `\chapter` numbering for each new `\part`.
Unfortunately, that didn't affect the unnumbered `\part*`s.

Manually setting the counter (`\setcounter{chapter}{0}`), seems to do the job as long as `hyperref` is not involved.
However, resetting the counter causes TOC to link the chapters in the unnumbered part to the chapters with the same local number from a previous part, which doesn't happen with automatically restarted chapters in numbered parts. E.g. "Discussion" points to "At First I Was Afraid".

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Foreword}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}
\chapter*{Achnowlegements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowlegements}
\part*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Introduction}
\chapter{Background}
\chapter{Related Work}
\part{Where It All Begun...}
\chapter{At First I Was Afraid}
\chapter{I Was Petrified}
\part*{Discussion and Future Work}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Discussion and Future Work}
\chapter{Discussion}
\chapter{Future Work}
\end{document}
```

`\@add to reset{chapter}{part*}` seems to have no effect at all.

What is the proper way to reset chapter numbering for both numbered and unnumbered parts?

Comment: What's the reason for an unnumbered part? Assuming that resetting the chapter number at parts is a good idea, which it isn't.

Comment: The unnumbered parts are the "intro" and "outro", they don't really deserve a number in my book.

Comment: Neither you need to restart chapter numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide clues for `hyperref` in order to distinguish equally numbered chapters. This can be done by redefining `\theHchapter`. For the last part, provide a suitable value for `\theHpart`.

Of course, your internal references to chapters will be clumsy: “in chapter 1 of the introduction part” or “in chapter 3 of part II”.

Avoid resetting chapter numbers, if you are not compelled to by some devious rule.

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}
\renewcommand{\theHchapter}{\theHpart.\thechapter}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Foreword}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}

\chapter*{Achnowlegements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowlegements}

\part*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Introduction}

\chapter{Background}
\chapter{Related Work}

\part{Where It All Begun...}
\chapter{At First I Was Afraid}
\chapter{I Was Petrified}

\part*{Discussion and Future Work}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}\renewcommand{\theHpart}{DFW}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Discussion and Future Work}

\chapter{Discussion}
\chapter{Future Work}

\end{document}
```

[image]