# How to correct hyperref when I setcounter of chapter of a part

Tags: hyperref

I am using package `hyperref`. When I click at Chapter one of part two in PDF file, I jump to Chapter one of part one. How can I jump to Chapter one of part two?
My code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \part{Part One}
    \chapter{Chapter one}
    \section{Section one}
        \section{Section two}
        \chapter{Chapter two}
    \section{Section three}
    \section{Section four}  
        \part{Part One}
        \setcounter{chapter}0
    \chapter{Chapter one}
    \section{Section one}
    \section{Section two}
    \chapter{Chapter two}
    \section{Section three}
    \section{Section four}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Adding `\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother  ` to the preamble instead of using `\setcounter{chapter}0` as described in the answer to [How to reset chapter and section counter with \part](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54386/134144)  should also work in your example: Alternatively, `\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}` should also do the trick.

Comment: Redefine \theHchapter so that is has a unique value for every chapter