# I need help with customizing my List of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, arabic, makeindex, latin

Lads,

I want to make a Table of Contents as show in. I've been using the default option, but it is not what I'm looking for.

this is what I want:

```
I. PART ONE
 I. Chapter one
  1. subsection A
  2. subsection B
 II. Chapter two
  1. subsection A
  2. subsection B
II. PART TWO
 I. Chapter one
  1. subsection A
  2. subsection B
 II. Chapter two
  1. subsection A
  2. subsection B
```

example:

[image]

my problem lies not in the structure of the book, but in the Table of Contents. For example, Parts are noted as "1", Chapters are noted as "1.1", and Subsections as "1.1.1". The core of my problem is only referencing Contents, not the overall structure of the book.

I'd appreciate your help

my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[width=3.93in, height=6.49in, top=1.0in, papersize={5.5in,8.2in}]{geometry}
\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\part{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vfil
  \secdef\@part\@spart}
\makeatother
%%%%%% CENTERED CHAPTER%%%%%%%
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\Large \centering}
\sectionfont{\normalsize \centering}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fancyhf{}
\lfoot[\thepage]{}
\rfoot[]{\thepage}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% % <-- this is new
  \fancyhf{} 
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} % same placement as with page style "fancy"
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\include{cover} 
\restoregeometry
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter
\part{Part1}
\chapter{A}
\chapter{B}
\chapter{C}
\part{Part2}
\chapter{A}
\chapter{B}
\chapter{C}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code you have so far, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: It would greatly help if you provided an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem and how you have tried to fix it. Default LaTeX does not produce non-English output so we have no idea what you might have done.

Comment: ok, it's fixed.

Comment: I don't think that you have fixed it. The regular command is `\chapter...` not `\Chapter...` I have no idea how many other errors you might have made.have made.and I have no intention of looking for them.  --GOM

Comment: ok, thank for nothing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset chapter and section counter with \part](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54383/how-to-reset-chapter-and-section-counter-with-part)

Comment: no, my problem lies not in the structure of the book, but in the Table of Contents. For example, Parts are noted as "1", Chapters are noted as "1.1", and Subsections as "1.1.1". The core of my problem is only referencing Contents, not the overall structure of the book.

Comment: Goodbye Chancy. Peter W.

Comment: Goodbye Peter, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me how exact to take your specification: do you want section headings to also omit the chapter number?  Do you want the periods to appear after the numbers?  This assumes yes and no, respectively.

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,openany]{book}
\counterwithin{chapter}{part}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Part1}
\chapter{A}\section{One}\section{Two}
\chapter{B}\section{One}\section{Two}
\chapter{C}\section{One}\section{Two}
\part{Part2}
\chapter{A}\section{One}\section{Two}
\chapter{B}\section{One}\section{Two}
\chapter{C}\section{One}\section{Two}
\end{document}
```

[image: code table of contents]

Some other things to note:

1. The level below `\chapter` is `\section`, not `\subsection`
2. There was a lot of code that wasn't relevant to your example.  It would have helped us understand things better if you'd taken that out.
3. Even with all of your code, it didn't include the `\tableofcontents` nor any `\(sub)sections`.